# Vue methods order of execution

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue app, and there is a method that calls data from an API and based on that data a filter data should be filled, so it can be rendered in some dropdown menus and based on that data other API calls should be performed. I use Vuex.

And I can't figure it out how to make that method called before the others on the Created Hook.

So, the method I need to be called at first, so the data to call the other methods is ready is 'actGetTabFilter'

This is the code where the filter is:

```
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row m-1 pt-2">
                <div class="col-sm" v-if="show == 1">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 w-auto m-auto">
                        <span
                          class="
                            font-RobotoBold
                            fs-16
                            font-weight-light
                            pr-2
                          "
                          >Área</span
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select
                          v-if="show == 1"
                          v-model="area_filter"
                          class="
                            dropdown-2
                            bor-rounded-xs bor-none
                            shadow-box-9
                            font-Roboto
                            text-capitalize
                            fs-14
                            w-100
                            p-md-2 p-1
                          "
                        >
                          <option :value="null" disabled>
                            Seleccionar...
                          </option>

                          <option
                            v-for="site in this.tabFilter.sites"
                            v-bind:value="site.id"
                            v-bind:key="site.id"
                            :selected="site.id == area_filter"
                          >
                            {{ site.name.toLowerCase() }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  v-if="show == 1 || show == 0"
                  :class="show == 0 ? 'col-sm-3' : 'col-sm'"
                >
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 w-auto m-auto">
                        <span
                          class="
                            font-RobotoBold
                            fs-16
                            font-weight-light
                            pr-2
                          "
                          >Año</span
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select
                          v-model="year"
                          class="
                            dropdown-2
                            bor-rounded-xs bor-none
                            shadow-box-9
                            font-Roboto
                            text-capitalize
                            fs-14
                            w-100
                            p-md-2 p-1
                          "
                        >
                          <option :value="null" disabled>
                            Seleccionar...
                          </option>

                          <option
                            v-for="year in this.tabFilter.years"
                            v-bind:value="year"
                            v-bind:key="'year' + year"
                            :selected="year == year"
                          >
                            {{ year }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  v-if="show == 1 || show == 0"
                  :class="show == 0 ? 'col-sm-3' : 'col-sm'"
                >
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 w-auto m-auto">
                        <span
                          class="
                            font-RobotoBold
                            fs-16
                            font-weight-light
                            pr-2
                          "
                          >Mes</span
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select
                          v-model="month"
                          class="
                            dropdown-2
                            bor-rounded-xs bor-none
                            shadow-box-9
                            font-Roboto
                            text-capitalize
                            fs-14
                            w-100
                            p-md-2 p-1
                          "
                        >
                          <option :value="null" disabled>
                            Seleccionar...
                          </option>

                          <option
                            v-for="month in this.tabFilter.months"
                            v-bind:value="month"
                            v-bind:key="'month' + month"
                            :selected="month == month"
                          >
                            {{ months_name[month] }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div :class="show == 0 ? 'col-sm-6' : 'col-sm-2'">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div
                        class="col ml-auto"
                        :class="show == 0 ? 'col-sm-3' : ''"
                      >
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class="
                            btn-red
                            bor-rounded-xs
                            w-100
                            float-right
                            p-0
                          "
                          style="height: 40px"
                          @click="filterAgain()"
                        >
                          Filtrar
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the code of the script:

```
export default {
  name: "Engagement",
  mixins: [cvMixin, psi],
  components: {
    SecondaryNavbar,
    MenuNavigation,
    BarChart,
    ButtonsMenu,
    IndicatorsButtons,
    LeaderRanking,
    DoughnutChart,
    FilterSwitch,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      is_data_fetched: false,
      area: null,
      area_filter: 7,
      area_personalities: 1,
      year: 2021,
      month: 3,
      filter: 1,
      classification: 1,
      actualIndicator: "",
      id: 1,
      actualIndicatorDesc: "",
      category: [1],
      categoryInfo: [],
      ranking: [],
      barData: {
        labels: [],
        data: [],
      },
      donutData: {
        name: null,
        labels: [],
        data: [],
        colors: [],
      },
      brandData: [],
      barThick: 15,
      site: "",
      show: 1,
      brand: {
        id: 0,
        name: null,
        description: null,
        image: null,
      },
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.area = this.user.core_vp_id;

    this.actGetTabFilter()
      .then(() => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.tabFilter;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.month = this.tabFilter.months.slice(-1)[0];
        this.year = this.tabFilter.years[0];
        this.isLoading = false;
      });

    this.actGetLeaders()
      .then(() => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.leadersList;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });

    this.actGetPersonalitiesAreas()
      .then(() => {
        this.personalitiesAreaList;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });

    this.getCategoriesInfo();

    //Get Ranking, Chart and Improve Ranking Data
    this.getGeneralFilterData(
      this.filter,
      this.category,
      this.year,
      this.month
    );

    this.getPersonalitiesData(this.area_personalities);

    this.actGetLeadersInfo({ leader: [[30000423, 25]], year: 2021, month: 3 })
      .then(() => {
        this.leadersInfo;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error: ", err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("modCore", ["user"]),
    ...mapState("modIndicators", [
      "tabFilter",
      "leadersList",
      "personalitiesAreaList",
      "categoriesListData",
      "generalFilterData",
      "personalitiesData",
      "leadersInfo",
    ]),
    title() {
      if (this.show == 2) {
        return "Personalidades de tu equipo";
      }
      return "Ranking Líderes - " + this.actualIndicator.toLowerCase();
    },
    datacollection() {
      return this.fillData();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("modIndicators", [
      "actGetTabFilter",
      "actGetLeaders",
      "actGetPersonalitiesAreas",
      "actGetCategoriesInfo",
      "actGetGeneralFilterData",
      "actGetPersonalitiesData",
      "actGetLeadersInfo",
    ]),
    fillData() {
      return this.donutData;
    },
    changeClassification(classification, id, name, description, show) {
      this.classification = classification;
      this.category = [id];
      this.id = id;
      this.actualIndicator = name;
      this.actualIndicatorDesc = description;
      if (show !== 2) {
        this.getGeneralFilterData(
          this.filter,
          this.category,
          this.year,
          this.month
        );
      }
      // this.updateRanking(id);
      this.updateImproveRanking(id);
    },
    changeShow(number) {
      this.show = number;
    },
    changeFilter() {
      if (this.filter === 1) {
        this.filter = 2;
        this.barThick = 20;
      } else {
        this.filter = 1;
        this.barThick = 15;
      }
      this.filterAgain();
    },
    filterAgain() {
      this.getCategoriesInfo();
      this.getGeneralFilterData(
        this.filter,
        this.category,
        this.year,
        this.month
      );
    },
    filterPersonalities() {
      this.getPersonalitiesData(this.area_personalities);
    },
    updateRanking(category_id) {
      this.ranking = Object.values(
        this.generalFilterData.filter((category) => {
          return category.id == category_id;
        })[0].ranking
      );
      this.ranking.sort(
        (a, b) => parseFloat(b.average) - parseFloat(a.average)
      );
    },
    updateImproveRanking(category_id) {
      this.categoryInfo = this.categoriesListData.filter((category) => {
        return category.id == category_id;
      });
    },
    getGeneralFilterData(filter, category, year, month) {
      // This filter brings the information for the bar chart
      this.actGetGeneralFilterData({
        filter: filter,
        category: category,
        year: year,
        month: month,
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.is_data_fetched = false;
          this.actualIndicator = this.generalFilterData[0].name;
          this.actualIndicatorDesc = this.generalFilterData[0].description;
          this.ranking = Object.values(
            this.generalFilterData.filter((category) => {
              return category.id == this.id;
            })[0].ranking
          ).sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.average) - parseFloat(a.average));

          let fetchedData = Object.values(
            this.generalFilterData.filter((category) => {
              return category.id == this.id;
            })[0].calculate
          );
          this.getChartData(fetchedData, this.filter);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Error: ", err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.is_data_fetched = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    getCategoriesInfo() {
      this.actGetCategoriesInfo({
        area: this.area_filter,
        year: this.year,
        month: this.month,
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.isLoading = true;
          this.categoryInfo = this.categoriesListData.filter((category) => {
            return category.id == this.id;
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Error: ", err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    getChartData(data, filter) {
      this.barData.labels.length = 0;
      this.barData.data.length = 0;
      if (filter == 2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.barData.labels.push(data[i].month);
          this.barData.data.push(Math.round(parseFloat(data[i].average)));
        }
      } else {
        data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.average) - parseFloat(a.average));
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let siteName = data[i].name.split(" ");
          for (let i = 0; i < siteName.length; i++) {
            siteName[i] =
              siteName[i].charAt(0) + siteName[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
          }
          this.barData.labels.push(siteName.join(" "));
          this.barData.data.push(Math.round(parseFloat(data[i].average)));
        }
      }
    },
    getPersonalitiesData(id) {
      this.actGetPersonalitiesData({
        id: id,
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.personalitiesData;
          this.is_data_fetched = false;
          this.isLoading = true;
          this.getBrandData();
          this.brand.id = this.personalitiesData.calculate[0].profile.id;
          this.brand.name = this.personalitiesData.calculate[0].profile.name;
          this.brand.description =
            this.personalitiesData.calculate[0].profile.description;
          this.brand.image = this.personalitiesData.calculate[0].profile.image;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error("Error: ", err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.is_data_fetched = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    getDonutData() {
      this.donutData.name = null;
      this.donutData.labels.length = 0;
      this.donutData.data.length = 0;
      this.donutData.colors.length = 0;
      this.donutData.name = this.personalitiesData.vp.name;
      this.brandData.sort(
        (a, b) => parseFloat(b.average) - parseFloat(a.average)
      );
      for (let i = 0; i < this.brandData.length; i++) {
        this.donutData.labels.push(this.brandData[i].profile.name);
        this.donutData.data.push(
          Math.round(parseFloat(this.brandData[i].average))
        );
        this.donutData.colors.push(this.brandData[i].color);
      }
    },
    changeBrand(id) {
      this.brand.id = id;
      this.filterBrand();
    },
    filterBrand() {
      let filteredBrand = this.personalitiesData.calculate.filter(
        (e) => e.profile.id == this.brand.id
      );
      this.brand.name = filteredBrand[0].profile.name;
      this.brand.description = filteredBrand[0].profile.description;
      this.brand.image = filteredBrand[0].profile.image;
      return filteredBrand;
    },
    getBrandData() {
      this.brandData = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.personalitiesData.calculate.length; i++) {
        this.personalitiesData.calculate[i].color = this.brandColors[i];
        this.brandData.push(this.personalitiesData.calculate[i]);
      }
      this.getDonutData();
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions :

1. put your other functions in the "then" of "actGetTabFilter"
2. use await and store the returned value

in both cases this will wait the response before executing the others functions

Comment: Thank you. The first one worked. But, Can you explain me the second option?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax

```
async created() {
    let response = await(YourAsyncFunction())
    //you can save it in data here if necessary
    YourOtherAsyncFunction()
}
```

this way it will wait the return of the first function before doing the second.
(don't forget to add `async` before your created methode)

Comment: if you need more info : [Async Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)